# how to remove status bar inside config file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using Phonegap to wrap HTML5 mobile app.
I have a problem when I want to remove status bar which is currently covering my header.

I have been adding some **preferences** inside **config.xml** file but unsuccessfully.

This is what I have added inside:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

But I don't see any changes.

Has someone came up with a solution for this?

Comment: what platform are you targeting?

Comment: @ulle I'm targeting iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting UIStatusBarHidden to true in your plist hides the status bar in iOS <= 6:

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
```

You can achieve the same thing programatically via: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]`

However, for iOS7 this doesn't seem to work. There you can override `prefersStatusBarHidden` in your view controller:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Since this method is available since iOS7, overriding it won't have any effect on iOS6.

Comment: I'm using jQuery mobile

Comment: What Phonegap/Cordova does is to provide a native wrapper app that shows your HTML5 app. In order to have this webview shown fullscreen, you need to adjust the native wrapper app.
If you stuck to the command line interface, the plist is located in platforms/ios/<project name>/<project name>Info.plist and your view conntroller is in platforms/ios/<project name>/Classes/MainViewController.m

Comment: I'm not using XCode...I just have all the html,js,css file inside one zio file and then I upload everything to phonegap which builds a ios and android app for me. I'm not using C++

Comment: I see... if you have no access to the plist and objective-c code, my solution is obviously not applicable to you.